# SwiftUI location permission does not show up

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I am trying to check the location permission on my app, but the app does not display the pop-up with all the options like "Always", "Only when using the app" or "never"

I am doing it when clicking on a buttom like below:

```
Button(action: {
                LocationManager.shared.requestLocationAuthorization()
                print("click to current" + searchText)
               }) {
               Text("Current Location)
            }
```

and then I am using the class below:

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    static let shared = LocationManager()
    private var locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
    private var requestLocationAuthorizationCallback: ((CLAuthorizationStatus) -> Void)?

    public func requestLocationAuthorization() {
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        let currentStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

        // Only ask authorization if it was never asked before
        guard currentStatus == .notDetermined else { return }

        if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
            self.requestLocationAuthorizationCallback = { status in
                if status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
                    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
                }
            }
            self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        } else {
            self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        }
    }
    public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
                                didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        self.requestLocationAuthorizationCallback?(status)
    }
}
```

Whatever I am doing, the pop to ask the user is not popping up.

the button is called in a VStack.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you sure its not returning from `guard currentStatus == .notDetermined else { return }` also you are not checking for other values of `currentStatus` if user has already given any kind of permission (notDetermined, when in user or always) iOS will not show permission pop up again, go to settings and check if you have already given any kind of permission already or put a breakpoint and check the value of `currentStatus`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the correct keys in your info.plist?

```
<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your description here</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your description here</string>
```

According to Apple, if these keys are missing.

> Important You must add the required keys to your app’s Info.plist
> file. If a required key isn’t present, authorization requests fail
> immediately.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/requesting_authorization_for_location_services